# how to increase the height of "container"

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have an below code.I would like to know how to increase the height of "container" class.I have check in google but unable to find any solution.Please check my below code and advise how to do this

```
<main class="d-flex align-items-center min-vh-100 py-3 py-md-0">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card login-card">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <img src="assets/images/login2.jpg" alt="login" class="login-card-img" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="brand-wrapper">
                                <img src="assets/images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo" style="width:130px;height:130px">
                            </div>
                            <p class="login-card-description">Sign In</p>
                            <form action="#!">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group mb-4">
                                    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="***********">
                                </div>
                                <input name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-block login-btn mb-4 text-align: center;" type="button" value="Login">
                            </form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In css file:

```
.container{
height: 1000px
}
```

OR

```
<div class="container" style= "height:1000px;">
```

Keep in mind that div and main are both block elements so it can be an idea to inspect that the main element does not block the height increase of the div.

Comment: it's not working please check attached file

Comment: Ok, so after some googling it looks like your main element is a block element aswell. With that in mind you need to look so the element main dont block the height increase of the div. You can easy do this by inspecting the elements and hoover the main element.

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to your `container`, just like in your `<main`:

```
<div class="container min-vh-100">
```

Comment: only adding a class doesn't increase the height of the container, please add some explanation

Comment: it's not working please check attached image for your ref..

Answer (score 0):

Try any one of the ways:

**External CSS**

```
.container {
  height: 1000px
}
```

**Inline CSS**

```
<div class="container" style="height: 1000px;">
```

Comment: sorry my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want only pass the image down, just like this?

```
<img src="assets/images/login2.jpg" alt="login" class="login-card-img" style="margin-top: 150px" />
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main class="d-flex align-items-center min-vh-100 py-3 py-md-0">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card login-card">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <img src="assets/images/login2.jpg" alt="login" class="login-card-img" style="margin-top: 150px" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="brand-wrapper">
                                <img src="assets/images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo" style="width:130px;height:130px">
                            </div>
                            <p class="login-card-description">Sign In</p>
                            <form action="#!">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group mb-4">
                                    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="***********">
                                </div>
                                <input name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-block login-btn mb-4 text-align: center;" type="button" value="Login">
                            </form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```